# Inconsistent authorization of AWS Java API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, authorization

I am trying to use AWS Java API to create a volume from my Java program.
Here is the sample code.

```
String accessKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
String secretKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
AmazonEC2Client client = new AmazonEC2Client(credentials);
client.setEndpoint("ec2.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:443");
CreateVolumeRequest request = new  CreateVolumeRequest(1, "ap-northeast-1c");
CreateVolumeResult volumeResponse = client.createVolume(request);
```

When I run this code on an AWS instance, this is running fine for the given credentials.

But If I run the same program with the same credentials from a machine on my corporate network. This is giving an exception.

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 401; Error Code: AuthFailure; Request ID: xxxxxxx)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1077)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:725)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:460)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:295)
    at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.invoke(AmazonEC2Client.java:9393)
    at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.createVolume(AmazonEC2Client.java:6707)
```

What could be the reason for this failure? 
One observation is that this is not happening consistently.
**Edit1:**
Since our local machines are behind NAT, The request as seen by AWS originates from only one public IP. If there are multiple clients are making API calls to AWS. Is there any chance that it limits the number of API requests and gives authorization failure exception. If so How do we know the limit of the number of requests for our account?

Comment: What is the Version of AWS SDK?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem by changing the time zone of my machine.